# Return highest and lowest number in a string of numbers with spaces

Tags: javascript, numbers

Let's say I have a string of numbers separated by spaces and I want to return the highest and lowest number. How could that best be done in JS using a function? Example:

```
highestAndLowest("1 2 3 4 5"); // return "5 1"
```

I would like the both numbers to be  returned in a string. The lowest number first followed by a space then the highest number.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction(str) {
    var tst = str.split(" ");
    return tst.max();
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/u4bhdxyf/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Math.min and [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max), and use them in an array to return the result, try:

```js
function highestAndLowest(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.split(" ");
  return Math.max.apply(null, numbers) + " " +  Math.min.apply(null, numbers)
}

document.write(highestAndLowest("1 2 3 4 5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a code that improves the solution and facilitates global use:

```js
/* Improve the prototype of Array. */

// Max function.
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

// Min function.
Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

var stringNumbers = "1 2 3 4 5";

// Convert to array with the numbers.
var arrayNumbers = stringNumbers.split(" ");

// Show the highest and lowest numbers.
alert("Highest number: " + arrayNumbers.max() + "\n Lowest number: " + arrayNumbers.min());
```

Answer (score 1):

**OK,** let's see how we can make a short function using ES6...

You have this string-number:

```
const num = "1 2 3 4 5";
```

and you create a function like this in ES6:

```
const highestAndLowest = nums => {
  nums = nums.split(" ");
  return `${Math.max(...nums)} ${Math.min(...nums)}`;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
highestAndLowest("1 2 3 4 5"); //return "5 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
  var temp = numbers.split(' ');
  temp.sort(function(a,b){return a-b; });
  return  temp[temp.length-1] + ' ' + temp[0];
}
```

did a little differently:
first split into an array, then sorted ... and returned the last (maximum) element with the first (minimum) element