# JavaScript - Convert string of space separated numbers to actual numbers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

When i console.log(); max, i get NaN, i already try a for loop (It's commented) but its not working. I already convert my string to an array.

This is my code.

```js
function numbersOutput(numbers) {

  var num = numbers.split(',');

  //for(var i=0; i<num.length; i++) { 
  //num[i] = parseInt(num[i], 0); 
  //} 

  var max = Math.max(num);
  console.log(max);

}
numbersOutput("1 2 3 4 5");
```

Comment: When you split a string, resulting value will also be string. You will have to parse it to numbers. Also `Math.max` takes only 2 args. Use `Math.max.apply(null, num)`

Comment: Well, your sending a string with spaces, and then asking to split on commas.

Comment: yes, but i need it to convert for a number, to use the Math.max(), to compare and get the highest number.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're splitting numbers on commas but the input is using spaces.

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](/help/mcve) before posting."*

Comment: @HugoSeleiro: `Math.max` will coerce what you pass it to number, FYI.

Comment: Sorry T.J, i dont understand

Comment: Split by space (better with regexp), use apply: `function numbersOutput(numbers) { var num = numbers.split(/\s+/); return Math.max.apply(null, num); }`

Comment: @Hugo, TJ is saying that Math.max expect's numbers, so it will convert strings into numbers for you.  eg. This will work,. `Math.max.apply(null,'1 10 4 11 7'.split(' '))`  even though split is returning strings.

Comment: Thanks Keith ;) !!

Comment: @HugoSeleiro As you requested for *tips/help*, **1.** refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916837/return-highest-and-lowest-number-in-a-string-of-numbers-with-spaces. I would have marked as dupe, but already voted to close. **2.** If you wish to reply/tag someone in comment, use **@** before name.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh !!

Comment: @HugoSeleiro Now that you have got the explanation and this post has already received few close votes, if you are satisfied with suggestion, you can remove this post. It will prevent receiving unwanted votes/comments like this one. If not, feel free to update question and someone will surely respond. Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function numbersOutput(numbers) {

  var num = numbers.split(' ');
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, num);
  console.log(max);

}
numbersOutput("1 2 3 4 5");
```

Comment: Thanks !! I got it work ;) !! Thank you very much !!